# Show that $f(x)\le f(1-x)$ for all $x\in(0,1/2]$ and all $q\in [0,2]$.

Tags: analysis, symmetric-functions

Let $f(x)=x^{q-1}\ln{(x)}$, with $q\in [0,2]$. Show that $$f(x)\le f(1-x)$$
for all $x\in(0,1/2]$.

I have plotted the function and I know that this is correct. But when I try to show this analytically, I am getting stuck (for instance, I write the whole expression $f(x)-f(1-x)$ and I try to manipulate it or I take the derivative but neither approach brings much).

Note also that the two expressions are almost equal close to $0$ and equal at $x=1/2$ so rough inequalities will not bring much. Equivalently $f(x)-f(1-x)$ is very close to zero when $x$ is close to $0$ or $x$ close to $1/2$.

Any hints?

Comment: What if $f(0)$?

Comment: Hint: if you are doing the quotient, that is, proving $\ln(x)/\ln(1-x)\ge (\frac{1-x}{x})^{q-1}$, you can find that you only need to do $q=2$ case. That is, $x\ln(x)\le (1-x)\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: Another hint: For $1/4\le x<1/2$, use the concavity and monotonicity to prove. For $0<x<1/4$, you can interleave it as $x\ln (x)\le -x\le (1-x)\ln(1-x)$

Comment: Thank you @JetfiRex! I will try both!